# I have installed slush-phaser-webpack globally but it is not working

Tags: javascript, npm, phaser-framework

I followed the doc of slush-phaser-webpack [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-phaser-webpack)

```
$ sudo npm install -g slush-phaser-webpack
```

Here is the output of npm :`└── slush-phaser-webpack@0.2.2`.
There is no error during installation.

I get this error`slush: command not found` after I type in 'slush'.

Env: mac osx el capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin slush-phaser-webpack is correctly installed.

> slush: command not found

This is because I didn't have slush installed on my computer.I need to install it first.Here is the code:

```
npm i slush -g
npm i --save-dev slush-phaser-webpack
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11097564)

Comment: @Review I solved this problem by myself.I want to close this question.This is the right answer.

Comment: the question says 'I have installed.....not working' and the answer says 'I should first install...'?? Then I think that's a silly mistake, or question is invalid

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11115465)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11115465)